# PHP Phalcon - Handling request and printing site content makes functions run multiple times

Tags: php, performance, phalcon

I'm noticing that when navigating to any part of my Phalcon site, everything seems to be firing twice. As shown below, `index.php` and the subsequent controllers are visited twice. I write to a text file in each of these, and the content is duplicated.

`index.php`

```
...
fwrite(fopen("log.txt", "a+"),"index\n");
...
```

`BaseController::onConstruct()`

```
...
fwrite(fopen("log.txt", "a+"), "base\n");
...
```

Which on any request gives the result:

`log.txt`

```
index
base
index
base
```

I think this has something to do with the handling and output of the request, as

`index.php`

```
$app = new Application($di);
try{
    $response = $app->handle();
    $response->send();
    ...
```

gives the above result, while

`index.php`

```
$app = new Application($di);
try{
    $response = $app->handle();
    //$response->send();
    ...
```

Gives the following result (and a blank screen in the browser, so not really a solution):

`log.txt`

```
index
base
```

I've tried a few different ways of getting hold of the output and printing it, but everything gives the same, duplicated result:

`index.php`

```
$response = $app->handle();
$content = $response->getContent();
echo $content;
```

and the one-liner

`index.php`

```
$app->handle()->send();
```

This happens on both `http` and `https` requests, so I don't think it's an Nginx/redirect issue.

Doing everything twice must be more costly than just the one time, 
so what can I do to have stuff only run once?

Could it be a resource being loaded later and doing some magic? I've looked for `<img>` tags with empty sources and am aware of some issues regarding favicons, especially in Chrome (though I'm certain I fixed an issue like that earlier in development), but the result is the same in Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

A small update: going to View Source in the browser gives the unduplicated result. Is there something in printing the actual content that could cause this issue?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Interesting issue, debugging myself. Also informed guys on the forum: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/18035/multiple-requests-in-the-bootstrap-file-not-the-favicon-issue Let us see who will get to the bottom of this first :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is no longer present after removing a call to `$this->assets->addCss()` on a non-existent CSS file. I had forgotten to remove the reference after removing the library from my project.

Additional information: "every broken image or assets makes an additional request to the index file" which causes this issue

Comment: Just figured out the same! On the dev version of the site I tested, there were 3 broken images, which made the additional requests! After fixing from 4 requests they went to 1. Everything is fine!

Please add to your answer that every broken image or assets makes an additional request to the index file, after that you can accept it as correct!

Comment: Did you figure exactly why this happens? @NikolayMihaylov

Comment: yes. For phalcon to work we are forwarding all http requests to the index.php. For example: website.com/image.jpg is treated as a route if image.jpg is not a valid file. If not a valid file dispatcher shows a 404 page which is correct behavior!